# Blender array modifier changes material when applied

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, modifiers, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to create a Street in Blender. Therefor I used the array modifier and created a sequence. The Street has a material which I created.

When I leave the modifier in the Stack, everything looks how I want it to be.
[image]

But when I press apply on the Modifier, it changes the fit of my material and makes it look striped. [image]

I dont see any reason for that and dont know how to fix it.
It would be great if anyone could explain how I can prevent this without leaving the modifier unapplied.
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your UV map is stretching. Could you unwrap it again after applying?

Answer (score 1):

This is a procedural texture (not an Image?) If so, it will default to using the *Generated* texture space. The *Generated* space measures 0-1 along the sides of an object's bounding box. However (I think inconsistently?), if an object is arrayed, the space takes its scale from the bounding box of a single element. When the Array modifier is applied, suddenly 0-1 is measured down the whole, (now single,) object.

You could use a *Texture Coordinate* node to put the texture into *Object* space. Then, you may have to tweak its scale, but it will be consistent, always considering the space of the entire array in Blender Units, (assuming no object-level scale transform,) applied or not.